# Do PHP Namespaces Autoload?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have the following directory structure:

`library/ex0/ex1/cURL`

But when I use `use namespace library\ex0\ex1\cURL` it doesn't work. Does this mean that you have to `include`, `require` or `__autoload` the class or is there an other way to automatically load?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: @Deadooshka is that a yes? You actually have to include the `PHP` file rather than simply cloning the namespace structure?